# When I press enter I can't create a new line in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, enter

When I press enter I can't create a new line in VSCODE (HTML5), I couldn't find the solution for this problem on the internet. The problem I am experiencing appears in the video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LD-kFMg_QSY

Comment: This is the standard behavior in vscode.

Comment: The  video is private and can't be viewed.

Comment: I had a similar problem (not limited to HTML5, though) after a recent VSCode update, and it turned out that I had one VSCode extension that malfunctioned. (To figure out which one, I just disable/enable the extensions one by one). Disabling that extension fixed the issue.

Comment: The above solution worked - I cleaned up my extensions and disabled/uninstalled a few while constantly checking if the problem was fixed. This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video shows you creating a new line. Perhaps your issue is with a plugin you installed or a problem with your keyboard.

Comment: But I can create new lines in Python and this problem does not appear. I don't think this problem is causing by my keyboard, I will delete all of the plugins I installed.

Comment: SequenceToSequence when I delete all plugins, my problem solved. Thanks for your help, but I didn't understand, which plugins made this problem? Thanks for your help again! Have a good day.

Comment: @c0xad Enable them one by one and see when the problem surfaces. Also take a close look at you `settings.json` and `keybinding.json` files

Comment: Same problem here. I must have hit some key combination that activated that feature. And no: no idea how to get back. VSCode definately has way to many features :-)

Comment: Possibly anecdotal, but the Python and PyLance extensions defaulted my keyboard's `insert` setting to True. So anytime these extensions are enabled, I need to tap insert once to get back to normal functionality.,

Comment: Here's how I fixed it. Go to `manage` (gear icon) > `Keyboard Shortcuts` (Ctlr+k, Ctlr+s) > Search for "Enter" > Find which extension is affecting the "Enter" keybinding and disable it. 
For me it was the ["vscode-styled-components"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=diegolincoln.vscode-styled-components)

Answer (score 7):

For anyone facing this issue, please open key binding setting and search for **Enter** key, find the extension that use Enter key for its functionality, in my case, I removed the **vscode-styled-components** extension and everything works fine again. I think the problem may be caused by a conflict in key binding functionality with another extension.

[image: vscode styled component extension]

Answer (score 0):

The link to your video is broken for me, but I found in my case that it was the *LaTeX Workshop* extension that grabbed the enter key. After uninstalling it, hitting enter worked fine once again.

Answer (score 0):

UNINSTALL   ....**auto-save** extension from vs code.
or
use it properly!!!--- by go-to>>>file>>>auto save...enable only for a proper file that you working on currently:)

Answer (score 0):

It's result of auto-saving and trimming settings. You should turn off auto save (go to settings > auto save > and switch "afterDelay" option to "off") or turn off trimming (settings > trim final whitelines > and uncheck the box)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a python script just reinstall the Python extension.

Answer (score -1):

Please update VS Code or uninstall the current VS Code and install the latest version of VS Code. The issue will be sorted out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).